# Limiting Versions On Deployment Server for ClickOnce

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

From the sounds of this StackOverflow answer it seems that when I publish my app for our company to use internally I have to manually remove the older "versions" from [Publish Directory]\Application Files.

I'm assuming this is correct, but is there any consequence to doing this?  I've read that ClickOnce does merging changes to application settings, but does it need the other versions for patching an upgrading app?

I'm concerned about the scenario where I have a user that has skipped upgrading for a version or two and when they do decide to upgrade the ClickOnce architecture requires that the deployment folder contain all the versions and the current most deployed version in order to upgrade.

This doesn't seem plausable to me, but can someone confirm that all I need in the folder is the latest version?  Also, any help in writing a Windows task to clean out all the older versions except the most recent would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Visual Studio to publish. If so, every time you publish it publishes the **entire** application.  Each published version is independent of one another. No need to keep previous versions other than having a backup around.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me.  I watch the update dialog download the whole app on every upgrade even when I've "tested" by skipping a few versions.  I guess I'll just need to write a task on the deployment server to keep only the latest version around.  The app is in source control so I don't see a need for having the deployed versions around so much (especially for an internal app).  Is there a manifest option to always force the upgrade?  I know there is one for a specific version.

Comment: A few comments. Actually, ClickOnce only downloads files from the server that have *changed*. This is confusing because the ClickOnce progress dialog always shows the size of the entire application, even if it's only downloading a single file. To confirm, run Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) during an update. This bug has been around forever and will probably never get fixed. Second, to force an upgrade set the "Minimum required version" to be the same as the ClickOnce version. This will make it so users can't skip updates.

Comment: "Second, to force an upgrade set the "Minimum required version" to be the same as the ClickOnce version." I guess I meant that I didn't want to have to increment that number whenever I pushed out a new build.

Comment: Why would you not want to increment the version number when you push out a new build? If the users have problems, how would you ever know exactly what version they were running, unless the app is online-only?